# How to add opacity to a theme of context in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a theme provider (dark and light theme) for my app after following some tutorials and it works. However, there are specific places where I would like to add some opacity. How can I do it given that I cannot add `.withOpacity` to a theme provider. You may refer to [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5OR.png).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

Theme.of(context).backgroundColor.withOpacity(0.6),

Answer (score 0):

When you set the iconTheme.color use the constructor **Color.fromRGBO()** instead, this works like (red,green,blue,***opacity***), and set the opacity value you need.

Example:

```
Color? theme = ThemeData.light().iconTheme.color;
//Before
theme = Colors.red;
//After
theme = const Color.fromRGBO(244, 67, 54, 0.5);
```

Comment: I did it on the theme provider as follows:

`iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(224, 224, 224, 1.0),
    ),`

However, when I want to use it with an opacity in another file like this:
`color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),` , there is a squiggly line under `withOpacity`